# Filtering on a Stringr Match (str_detect) EXCEPT For a Particular Similar Value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to create a dplyr pipeline to filter on

Imagine a data frame `jobs`, where I want to filter out the most-senior positions from the `titles` column:

```
titles

Chief Executive Officer
Chief Financial Officer
Chief Technical Officer
Manager
Product Manager
Programmer
Scientist
Marketer
Lawyer
Secretary
```

R code for filtering them out (up to 'Manager') would be...

```
jobs %>% 
filter(!str_detect(title, 'Chief')) %>%
filter(!str_detect(title, 'Manager')) ...
```

but I want to still keep "Program Manager" in the final filtering to produce a new data frame with all of the "lower level jobs" like

```
Product Manager
Programmer
Scientist
Marketer
Lawyer
Secretary
```

Is there a way to specify the str_detect() filter on a given value EXCEPT for one particular string?

Assume that the data frame's column has 1000s of roles, with various string combinations including "Manager," but there will always be a filter on a specific exception.

Comment: Why not simply use anchors to "Manager" like so `... %>% filter(!stringr::str_detect(title, "^Chief|^Manager$))`. The `^` anchor tells the regex to match strings starting with "Manager". The other anchor `$` ensures that the string must also end with "Manager".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you could have a separate `filter` for "Product Manager"

```
library(tidyverse)

jobs %>% 
filter((!str_detect(title, "Chief|Manager")) | str_detect(title, "Product Manager"))


#            title
#1 Product Manager
#2      Programmer
#3       Scientist
#4        Marketer
#5          Lawyer
#6       Secretary
```

---

which can be also twisted in base R using `grepl/grep`

```
jobs[c(grep("Product Manager",jobs$title), 
       grep("Chief|Manager", jobs$title, invert = TRUE)),, drop = FALSE]
```